# Apache Storm Flux Kafka Spout Record Translator Exception

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-flux

I am using storm flux **1.2.2** to deploy topology. I am passing record translator to KafkaSpoutConfig (referred from -> https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/flux/flux-examples/src/main/resources/kafka_spout.yaml), but getting following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.storm.flux.examples.OnlyValueRecordTranslator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildObject(FluxBuilder.java:342)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildComponents(FluxBuilder.java:421)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildTopology(FluxBuilder.java:101)
    at com.gsl.saf.storm.flux.manager.CustomFluxManager.runFlux(CustomFluxManager.java:87)
    at com.gsl.saf.storm.flux.manager.StromTopologyManager.SubmitTopology(StromTopologyManager.java:185)
    at com.gsl.saf.storm.flux.manager.StromTopologyManager.submitTopology(StromTopologyManager.java:299)
    at com.gsl.saf.stormflux.App.main(App.java:36)
```

Flux yaml config :

```
      components:

  - id: "windowDuration"
    className: "org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseWindowedBolt$Duration"
    constructorArgs:
      - 10
      - "SECONDS"
  - id: "onlyValueRecordTranslator"
    className: "org.apache.storm.flux.examples.OnlyValueRecordTranslator"

  - id: "spoutConfigBuilder"
    className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpoutConfig$Builder"
    constructorArgs:
      - "localhost:9092"
      - ["test_topic"]
    properties:
      - name: "firstPollOffsetStrategy"
        value: EARLIEST
      - name: "recordTranslator"
        ref: "onlyValueRecordTranslator"
    configMethods:
      - name: "setProp"
        args:
          - {
              "key.deserializer" : "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
              "value.deserializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
            }

  - id: "spoutConfig"
    className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpoutConfig"
    constructorArgs:
      - ref: "spoutConfigBuilder"
config:
  topology.workers: 1

# spout definitions
spouts:
  - id: "spout-1"
    className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpout"
    constructorArgs:
      - ref: "spoutConfig"
```

POM config :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>flux-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`OnlyValueRecordTranslator` only exists in the `flux-examples` project. See https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/flux/flux-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/flux/examples/OnlyValueRecordTranslator.java. You can copy it into your project if you like.

Comment: copied OnlyValueRecordTranslator.java from flux-examples into my project.while debugging I found that findSetter method of FluxBuilder class was providing setRecordTranslator(Func<ConsumerRecord<K, V>, List<Object>> func, Fields fields) and we were expecting setRecordTranslator(RecordTranslator<K, V> translator),because of which "wrong argument exception" was thrown. So I changed yaml file by adding recordTraslator in configMethods and  it worked 
configMethods:
      - name: "setRecordTranslator"
        args: [ref: "onlyValueRecordTranslator"]

Comment: I am facing "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch" when i used the same yml. Could you please put the yaml which worked for you?